# Can I have 2 two home pages (authenticated and anonymous) in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

The "content" section in my "home page" should be a Sign In widget I built, but once signed in I want people to be sent to see a "content" zone that is something they're now permissioned to see. For both pages I want people to be able to just visit my URL without anything after the URL name. (i.e. www.xyz.com) and see different "content" zone whether signed in, or not.

The problem I am facing is that Orchard sets "Authenticated" and "Anonymous" as layers, but what you set on those layers has to be set for every single page on the site. But my "home page" has different stuff happening than other pages on my site.

Is there a way, I can set separate content sections of the home page (i.e. when people just type in the base URL of my site) for both Authenticated and Anonymous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A URL should correspond to a resource. Having two different resources behind a single URL, with the GET verb, affects SEO negatively, among other nasty effects. One thing you can do however, is redirect your authenticated users, from your home page, to a separate URL.

If you still want to go ahead with this, you can define your own layers that combine the conditions for home and for authenticated: `url('~/') and Authenticated` and `url('~/') and not Authenticated` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you can give me a line of code I can insert somewhere that will redirect my users to a certain URL if it recognizes that they are authenticated?

Comment: if (Request.IsAuthenticated) Response.Redirect("/auhtenticatedhome");

Comment: Ideally you'd probably put that in a filter, but if you're looking for the simplest way to make it work, you could put it in a layout-url-homepage.cshtml theme template override. Clearly not as clean but will get the job done.
@user1723364: how about granting the answer?